# How to add onclick() in pdfjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, pdf.js

I'm trying to add a onclick() event in pdfjs.

I have tried adding a method to handle the onclick in pdf.js file. I'm getting this error on click "Uncaught ReferenceError: displayAttachmentsOnLocation is not defined".

In Html:

```
<div class="page-margin" onclick="displayAttachmentsOnLocation(1)">
```

In Pdf.js :

```
function displayAttachmentsOnLocation(locationId) {
   var panel = parent.angular.element(parent.document.getElementById('attachments-panel')).scope().vm;
   panel.displayAttachmentsOnLocation(locationId);
 }
```

I want to call the displayAttachmentsOnLocation() onclick event on pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use the `ng-click=""` directives like that:

```
<div class="page-margin" ng-click="$ctrl.displayAttachmentsOnLocation(1)"></div>
```

Another think, you haven't specified the name of the controller when you call the method.

Controller:

```
  angular.module('app', ['$scope']).controller('repeatController', function($scope) {

  $scope.displayAttachmentsOnLocation = (locationId) => {
      // Write here the logic
  };
});
```

If you want to add onclick event on pdfjs:

```
var element = document.getElementById('idElement');
element.addEventListener('click, (event) => {
   // Do some logic here when click event is fired
});
```

Comment: My question is about adding onclick event on third party library "pdf.js".

Comment: I update my answer. If you use addEventListener(..) you can add any event